# Using grep in a for loop in bash

Tags: bash, awk

So, I have 2 files: the first one is a list of names, including not only alpha-numeric characters (for instance an entry like "John$on"). The second one is a list of strings.
My goal is creating a script that is able to take all the entries in the file 1 and look for them in the file 2 and finally produce a file with all the lines from file 2 that include each word from file 1.
I have tried with Bash scripting but

```
for line in $file1
do
    cat $line
    grep -Pi $line $file2 >> final_list.txt
done
```

doesn't do the trick. I tried also putting $line between "" but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `grep -xf file1 file2` ?

Comment: Please also post examples of input and output. This can increase the changes of receiving the answer you are looking for.

Comment: `it doesn't work` is the worst possible problem statement as it tells us nothing about the problem you're having. When asking for help with your broken software/car/marriage/arm/whatever always state in what way it "doesn't work" so people can best help you. Also, copy/paste your software into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about then [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with the updated code, requirements, problem statement and missing sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for but without sample input/output it's a guess:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    words[$0]
    next
}
{
    for (word in words) {
        if ( !index(" "$0" "," "word" ") ) {
            next
        }
    }
    print
}
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice that the emulator I was using automatically selected Perl Regex and that affected my original script.

Answer (score 0):

> … with all the lines from file 2 that include each word from line 1.

Surely you meant file 1 instead of *line 1*. Unfortunately `grep` has no option to only output lines where all patterns match, but we can use it to preselect lines with any match and test these for the presence of the total number of matches:

```
n=`wc -l <$file1`
grep -f$file1 $file2 |
while read line
do  [ `grep -of$file1 <<<"$line" | sort -u | wc -l` -eq $n ] && echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell about some of the issues. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some others.